# How to test both changes in state and return value?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests

I have this problem. I have a method in a class which gives me some return value. This method also makes changes to the state of the instance of that class. I need to unit test them both, so I made the test cases for the return value and copied them and just changed the assert from testing the return value to testing the change in representation (the only way for me to test this class is to test its representation). However, this does not seem like a very good way to deal with this. If I ever have changes in the functionality of the class, I will have to change the Act in the AAA in both test cases. How do I go about testing this? Is there some pattern to do that? Having both asserts in one test would mean I would be testing two things in one test case. In some languages (like JavaScript), I know I can make an array of tuples with the functionality, the assert for the return value and the assert for the representation, but I'm not sure a) how much better that is over some copy-pasting and b) what to do in other languages (e.g. in C# I imagine I'd have to make some classes with the asserts and include them in test cases).

Edit: For example:

```
class A {
state;

foo(animal, foodAmount) {
    let returnResult = {};
    //does things with animal and foodAmount
    //which things change BOTH returnResult and the state variable
    return returnResult;
}

bar() {
    let stateToReturn = "";
    //state is used to change the stateToReturn variable
    return stateToReturn;
}
```

}

Here I will test function foo with a) an animal that does not exist currently, b) an animal that exists where I will add a non-zero amount of food to make sure the amount of food changes, c) two different animals to make sure they do not interfere with each other's food amounts, etc. I will do all these tests and make sure the returnResult variable is correct. The problem is that I need to make sure it does not only affect the returnResult variable, but also the state. The bar function is the only way for me to see the inner state. How would I go about testing the foo function? Would I write all tests twice (once to check foo returns the correct result and once to check foo changes the state correctly)?

Comment: Could you please provide more context and/or code samples? The question is rather generic. I could give some generic advice, but this may lead to mindless testing.

Comment: @PhilipWeinke I added an example. Sorry for adding it so late, but I couldn't add it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Even with your example it's still a bit vague. The general and short answer to your question is: You should test for behavior, not methods. If that requires you to make assertions on the result of multiple methods in one test that's perfectly fine.

You shouldn't, however, expose the internal state of your class just to make it testable. It's better to test against the public api of your class. After all, that's how the production code interacts with it.

If a method changes the internal state but there is nothing in the public api that makes the change visible, how do you test it? You probably have a hidden concept in your class that should be extracted into its own class with its own public api. You can test the new class independently and the interaction between the two classes. This leads to smaller and more focused tests.

I'm not sure if this answers your question sufficiently but maybe there's some food for thought.